Do transversal gates need to exactly preserve the stabilizer group?
When we consider whether a transversal gate corresponds to a logical gate, we need to check whether the application of the transversal gate preserves the stabilizer group. What I don't understand is that, does it need to "exactly" preserve the stabilizer group? For example, in the hexagonal color code, people say transversally applying $S^\dagger$ gates is not enough because 6-body $X$ stabilizers $X^{\otimes 6}$ become $-X^{\otimes 6}$ (up to multiplication of $Z^{\otimes 6}$). However, I think just reinterpreting syndrome of these stabilizer is enough. More specifically, suppose we have a code with a stabilizer group $<A, B, C>$. Then, if it changes to $<-A, B, C>$ by a transversal operation, just interpreting $+1$ syndrome of $A$ as $-1$ and $-1$ syndrome of $A$ as $+1$ in the subsequent computation seems enough as long as the operation to the logical state is what we expect. So, it seems to me that just applying transversal $S^\dagger$ gates is enough for the logical $S$ gate in the hexagonal color code. What am I missing?

Do you have concrete examples of "people" making such a claim? I would tend to agree with you, but there might be some contexts where exact preservation is relevant.

@AG47 In https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0069, they apply $S$ gates to some qubits and $S^\dagger$ gates to other qubits so that transversal $S$ and  $S\dagger$ gates preserve stabilizer group in the hexagonal color codes. I understand some $S^\dagger$ gates are needed to make the logical action logical $S$, but I don't understand why they apply mixed $S$ and $S^\dagger$ rather than just applying transversal $S^\dagger$ gates.

In the paper you linked, a footnote explicitly mentions that "Preservation of the stabilizer group is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition that implies preservation of the code".
Their goal is to show that $S$ can be (weakly) transversally implemented. To this end, they verify its action on the stabilizers and logical operators. For their alternating pattern of $S$ and $S^{\dagger}$ gates, the stabilizer group is exactly preserved.
Using $S^{\dagger\otimes n}$ is equivalent to using their pattern and performing additionnal $Z$ gates, which would be normally detected as $Z$ errors since they flip the generators of the $X$-stabilizers of the code.
I think that stricto sensu your operation does not preserve the code, since the stabilizer group has some modified generators (initially not part of the stabilizer group).
However, as you noted, by adjusting accordingly the expected measurement outcomes, one can keep going with the error-corrected computation. This adjustement acknowledging that some stabilizers have changed is similar to code-switching between the regular color code and a slighlty modified color code (where the codespace lives inside the common -1-eigenspace of the previous $X$-stabilizers).
Since the logical operators of both versions of the color codes are the same, the code-switching is trivial (note however that you might have implemented a logical $S^{\dagger}$ gate instead of a logical $S$ gate).
Hence, what you propose is certainly a valid logical gate which, from the point of view of error spreading, is transversal. Whether it does qualify as a transversal operation of the color code is debatable, but for practical purposes, both designs should work with their own merit. Your design is strongly transversal (all qubits undergo the same operator) but requires some classical post-processing of the syndrome, the other design requires the ability of performing both $S$ and $S^{\dagger}$.
